# how to use htacces rewrite code for 3 diffrent files

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i trying to make 3 diffrent files diffrent url i use currently below code whis is work perfect for me.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ file.php?file=$1
```

and i feel i need  more urls for 2 other files and i change this code as below but this not work it change url fine but it not redirect me to contact.php its redirect to file.php as above code work.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ contact.php?contact=$1
```

so i need to help for make 3 files diffrent urls.

Answer (score 0):

How is apache supposed to tell the difference between a request that's supposed to go to file.php or a request that's supposed to go to contact.php? They look completely identical. You'll have to preface it with something unique, like:

```
RewriteRule ^file/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ file.php?file=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ contact.php?contact=$1 [L]
```

So the URLs will look like:

```
http://example.com/file/foo.html
http://example.com/comtact/bar.html
```

Comment: hey thanks for reply but its not work. when i click for file.php its show page not found. and url show : `http://localhost/www/nokia-lumia.html` and contact.php file also not work